# VBS : Create a local admin account

Tags: vbscript, windows-7

I'm using the VBS script below to create a local user account and add it to the administrators group, however when I run it ,it creates the account but I get an exception when it tries to add it to the local admin group.

```
    Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &h10000

' specify account to create 
strAccount = "user"
strPswd = "password"

' get local computer name 
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
strComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName

' check if local account already exists
intExists = 0
Set colAccounts = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "")
colAccounts.Filter = Array("user")
For Each objUser In colAccounts
    If objUser.Name = strAccount Then
        intExists = 1
    End If
Next

If intExists = 0 Then

   ' create local user 
   Set colAccounts = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "") 
   Set objUser = colAccounts.Create("user", strAccount) 

   ' set pswd 
   objUser.SetPassword strPswd
   objUser.SetInfo

   ' add to local admins group 
   Set objGroup = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/Administrators,group")
   Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/" & strAccount & ",user")
   objGroup.Add(objUser.ADsPath)

   ' set password to not expire
    intUserFlags = objUser.Get("UserFlags")
    objUser.put "Userflags", intUserFlags Or ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD
    objUser.SetInfo

End If
```

here is the error message i'm getting :

[image: CBuqX.jpg]

Comment: After you apply the new password with `objUser.SetInfo`, you probably also want to make sure the account is not disabled `objuser.AccountDisabled = False` (so it shows in the Manage Accounts panel) and not locked (reset the flag for "too many failed login attempts") `objUser.IsAccountLocked = False`.

Answer (score 2):

Missing something in `GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "")`. Use

```
' create local user 
Set colAccounts = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & ",computer") 
Set objUser = colAccounts.Create("user", strAccount)
```

Not having energy and fortitude to analyze it more or deeper: here is my (cca 10 years old) script:

```
' VB Script Document - create & manage a local user account 

option explicit
On Error Goto 0
Dim WshShell, WshNetwork, objGroup, objComputer, objUser _
  , strUserObjectName, strUserObjectPass , strUserObjectDesc, strUserObjectFull _
  , strResult, strCOMPUTERNAME, strCurrentUser, _
  , lngUserProperties, lngUF

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set objGroup = Nothing
strResult = ""
strCOMPUTERNAME = WshNetwork.ComputerName
strCurrentUser  = WshNetwork.UserName

If AmIAnAdmin() Then
Else
  '''
  Wscript.Echo strResult, "I am not an Admin"
  Wscript.Quit
End If

'******************************************************'
'************ CHANGE  NEXT FOUR LINES *****************'
  strUserObjectName = "Student" 
  strUserObjectPass = "P@ssw0rd"
  strUserObjectDesc = "a student of our school"
  strUserObjectFull = "new student"
'************ CHANGE ABOVE FOUR LINES *****************'
'******************************************************'

Set objComputer = GetObject("WinNT://" & strCOMPUTERNAME & ",computer")

' Turns error processing on, disables error prompts in the interface
' and allows the script to continue
On Error Resume Next

' try to connect to user object to see if account is a local user
Set objUser = objComputer.GetObject( "user", strUserObjectName)

If Err.Number = 0 Then
  ' local user exists
    On Error Goto 0
  strResult = "Updated "
    ' Do not change Password of existing local account  
  '''objUser.SetPassword strUserObjectPass
    ' Set account so its not disabled
    objuser.accountdisabled = False
    ' Set account so its not locked (unlock account)
  objUser.IsAccountLocked = False
  lngUserProperties = setUserProperties( False)
    'Activate the above settings
    objUser.SetInfo
Else
  ' local user does not exist -> create it
    On Error Goto 0
  strResult = "Created "
    'Create account and populate account info
    Set objUser = objComputer.Create( "user", strUserObjectName)
    objUser.SetPassword strUserObjectPass
    objUser.SetInfo
    objUser.FullName = strUserObjectFull
    objUser.Description = strUserObjectDesc
  lngUserProperties = setUserProperties( True)
  'Activate the above settings
    objUser.SetInfo
End If

Err.Clear 'Clears any error numbers returned from above lines

'Add account to desired groups
addAccoutToALocalGroup "Users", Not booRemoveMembership
addAccoutToALocalGroup "Power Users", Not booRemoveMembership
addAccoutToALocalGroup "Debugger Users", Not booRemoveMembership
addAccoutToALocalGroup "Administrators", Not booRemoveMembership

lngUF = objUser.Get( "userFlags")
''' 
Wscript.echo strResult, strCOMPUTERNAME, strUserObjectName _
      , "0x" & Hex( lngUserProperties)
'''

Function setUserProperties( ByVal booNewUser)
    lngUF = objUser.Get( "userFlags")
  If booNewUser Then
    ''' force user to change password at next logon
    lngUF = lngUF Or ADS_UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED
  Else
  End If
    ' Lock out Account? Or need to be used objUser.IsAccountLocked = True?
    'lngUF = lngUF Or ADS_UF_LOCKOUT
    ' Disable Account? Or need to be used objuser.accountdisabled = True?
  'lngUF = lngUF Or ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE
  ' Set User so he cannot change password 
    'lngUF = lngUF Or ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE
    ' Set Password so it doesn't expire
  'lngUF = lngUF Or ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD
    ' Set Account Password is not required (allow empty password)
  'lngUF = lngUF Or ADS_UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD
  ''' Or ADS_UF_Unknown ''' not valid trying {objUser.SetInfo} 
    objUser.Put "userFlags", lngUF
    setUserProperties = lngUF
End Function ''' setUserProperties

' Adds account to a local group;
' returns zero if successfull; otherwise, returns error number 
Function addAccoutToALocalGroup( strLocalGroup, booRemove)
  On Error Resume Next
  ' try to connect to group object
  Set objGroup = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputerName _
    & "/" & strLocalGroup & ",group")
  addAccoutToALocalGroup = Err.Number
  Select Case addAccoutToALocalGroup
  Case 0
    ' local group exists
    On Error Goto 0
    If booUserIsInGroupAlready() Then
      If booRemove Then
        objGroup.Remove( objUser.ADsPath)
      Else
      End If
    Else
      If booRemove Then
      Else
        objGroup.Add( objUser.ADsPath)
      End If
    End If
  Case -2147022676
    ' local group does not exist
    ''Wscript.Echo "local group does not exist:" & strLocalGroup 
      On Error Goto 0
  Case Else
    ' another error occured
    ''Wscript.Echo "Error # " & Hex(Err.Number) & " " & _
    ''  CStr(Err.Number) & " " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & _
    ''  "on user "  & strUserObjectName & " " & sUserDesc & vbNewLine & _
    ''  "computer " & strComputerName & vbNewLine & _
    ''  "on group " & strLocalGroup
      On Error Goto 0
  End Select
End Function ''' addAccoutToALocalGroup

Function booUserIsInGroupAlready
  booUserIsInGroupAlready = False
  Dim objUserLoc
  For Each objUserLoc In objGroup.Members
    If StrComp( objUserLoc.Name, strUserObjectName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
      ' strUserObjectName & " is already a member of this group: " & objGroup.Name
      booUserIsInGroupAlready = True
      Exit For
    Else
    End If
  Next 'objUserLoc
End Function ''' booUserIsInGroupAlready

Function AmIAnAdmin
  Set objGroup = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputerName & "/Administrators,group")
  AmIAnAdmin = False
  Dim objUserLoc
  For Each objUserLoc In objGroup.Members
    If StrComp( objUserLoc.Name, strCurrentUser, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
      AmIAnAdmin = True
      Exit For
    Else
    End If
  Next 'objUserLoc
  Set objGroup = Nothing
End Function ''' AmIAnAdmin

CONST booRemoveMembership = True
'
'BEGININING OF FILE http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/trench/659.html#tonyp
'
Const ADS_UF_SCRIPT                                 =        1  '       0x1
Const ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE                         =        2  '       0x2
Const ADS_UF_unknown                                =        4  '       0x4
Const ADS_UF_HOMEDIR_REQUIRED                       =        8  '       0x8
Const ADS_UF_LOCKOUT                                =       16  '      0x10
Const ADS_UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD                         =       32  '      0x20
Const ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE                     =       64  '      0x40
Const ADS_UF_ENCRYPTED_TEXT_PASSWORD_ALLOWED        =      128  '      0x80
Const ADS_UF_TEMP_DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT                 =      256  '     0x100
Const ADS_UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT                         =      512  '     0x200
Const ADS_UF_INTERDOMAIN_TRUST_ACCOUNT              =     2048  '     0x800
Const ADS_UF_WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT              =     4096  '    0x1000
Const ADS_UF_SERVER_TRUST_ACCOUNT                   =     8192  '    0x2000
Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD                     =    65536  '   0x10000
Const ADS_UF_MNS_LOGON_ACCOUNT                      =   131072  '   0x20000
Const ADS_UF_SMARTCARD_REQUIRED                     =   262144  '   0x40000
Const ADS_UF_TRUSTED_FOR_DELEGATION                 =   524288  '   0x80000
Const ADS_UF_NOT_DELEGATED                          =  1048576  '  0x100000
Const ADS_UF_USE_DES_KEY_ONLY                       =  2097152  '  0x200000
Const ADS_UF_DONT_REQUIRE_PREAUTH                   =  4194304  '  0x400000
Const ADS_UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED                       =  8388608  '  0x800000
Const ADS_UF_TRUSTED_TO_AUTHENTICATE_FOR_DELEGATION = 16777216  ' 0x1000000
'
' default userFlags value = 0x201
'
'END OF FILE http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/trench/659.html#tonyp

'END OF FILE
```